# 'This' scope changes when calling function from array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

For code shortness I'm trying to store some similar functions inside an array, and call the correct function depending on a numeric key.

Each function returns a Promise, that actually wraps an Observable, I'm fecthing some data and pushing it to the corresponding data array.
Calling each individual functions works fine, but when I'm trying to call them from the functions array (event based call), the "this' keyword refers to the function array instead of the class.

Here is the code:

```
public currentKey = 0;
...
constructor(private api: ApiService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadTrending(0); //THIS WORKS!
    this.loadNews(0);
    ....
    this.loadingMethods = [this.loadTrending, this.loadNews, this.loadCrowdfunding, this.loadUpcoming]

  }

  loadData(event) {

    this.loadingMethods[this.currentKey](this.offsets[this.currentKey]).then(bool => {
      event.target.complete(); // THIS DOESN'T WORK

    });

  }

 public loadTrending(offset: number): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.api.trending(offset).subscribe(trending => { //'THIS' REFERS HERE TO THE ARRAY
        this.gameLists[this.TRENDING_KEY].push(...trending.list);
        resolve(true);
      });
    });
  }
```

Is there a way to achieve this function call and have this refering to the class as usual ?

EDIT : I'm already using ECMA6 arrow functions that works througout all my project, so I don't think [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) is the answer here. Even though it is well explained there.

Error is:

```
core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'trending' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'trending' of undefined
    at news.page.ts:68
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:910)
```

Thanks.

Comment: try using **arrow functions** like:  `loadData = (event) => {}`and `public loadTrending = (offset: number) => {}` and so on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Where is `loadData()` called?

Comment: An alternative: `this.loadingMethods = [this.loadTrending.bind(this), ...]`.

Comment: Could you post the error message as well. It might be helpful here.

Comment: @Pointy loadData is called when an event (ionInfinite) is fired.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesRouillé using `.bind()` as in the comment above is probably what you'll have to do. The value of `this` is the array because that's how `this` works normally.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks, that did the trick. I didn't think I had to use that method since I was using arrow functions, but it makes sense now thanks to all the resources you gave me.

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by @ConnorsFan & @Pointy.

Need to to use .bind() in my array since calling a method from an array will normally change the context of 'this' even though I'm using arrow functions.

```
this.loadingMethods = [this.loadTrending.bind(this), ...]
```

Thanks.